# Codename one: App should close on Double press on back button

Tags: codenameone

My app should exit on double press of back button.On first press "press back again to exit" this message should come and on second press app should get close.What should I do for that in codenae one?
I have attached screenshot which I want to do on back press in codename one.
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't support that behavior but you can use a bit of an implementation behavior hack. The back button in Android is encoded as `-23452` so you can override `keyReleased` in `Form` and don't call super:

```
private long lastTimeReleased = -1;
public void keyReleased(int keyCode) {
    if(keyCode == -23452) {
       // back key was released once, use your system logic

       // return so normal key behavior doesn't happen here...
       return;
    }
    // allow other keys to process normally
    super.keyReleased(keyCode);
}
```